Variable en codigo dinamico SQL Server
Quiero realizar la asignacion de 1 de manera dinamica de acuerdo a la variable que se ingrese en el sp, es posible?
@ENTRADA NVARCHAR(90) = 'PEDRO'
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @PRESENTACION_PEDRO INT; SET @PRESENTACION_PEDRO = 0;
DECLARE @PRESENTACION_JUAN INT; SET @PRESENTACION_JUAN = 0;
DECLARE @x INT;

set @X = 'SET @PRESENTACION_'+@ENTRADA+' = 1;'
exec sp_executesql @x


Tu código tiene demasiados problemas. El principal es que tu código está abierto a inyección de SQL y eso es un problema de seguridad terrible. Pero además hay errores de sintaxis y en los tipos de datos. Te sugiero que expliques el problema que quieres resolver con esto para darte una mejor alternativa.

Si la cantidad de posibilidades fuera razonable, no necesitás hacer nada de lo que preguntas, simplemente set @X = CASE WHEN @ENTRADA = 'PEDRO' THEN @PRESENTACION_PEDRO ELSE @PRESENTACION_RECAMIER_TALCOS END

El problema que tienes es que, al invocar a sp_executesql, cambias de ámbito (scope), y las variables locales no van a ser visibles ni pueden ser modificadas en el ámbito nuevo. Podrías pasar todas las variables como parámetros al nuevo ámbito, pero terminarías teniendo el mismo problema dentro de este. Creo, sin embargo, que podemos estar ante un problema xy. Si editas la pregunta y nos explicas qué es lo que buscas resolver, quizás encuentres la ayuda que buscas. Si lo haces, dejame un comentario y veo si está en mis manos ayudarte. Saludos.

Tu idea es interesante, pero el problema principal es que no puedes construir directamente el nombre de una variable dinámica en SQL Server de esa manera.
Sin embargo, puedes usar una tabla temporal o un diccionario para simular este comportamiento dinámico, o usar código dinámico de otra manera.
CREATE PROCEDURE AsignacionDinamica
@ENTRADA NVARCHAR(90)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @PRESENTACION_PEDRO INT = 0;
DECLARE @PRESENTACION_JUAN INT = 0;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = 'SET @PRESENTACION_' + @ENTRADA + ' = 1';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
    N'@PRESENTACION_PEDRO INT OUTPUT, @PRESENTACION_JUAN INT OUTPUT', 
    @PRESENTACION_PEDRO OUTPUT, 
    @PRESENTACION_JUAN OUTPUT;

--Pongo este select para poder ver tu resultado
SELECT @PRESENTACION_PEDRO AS PRESENTACION_PEDRO, 
       @PRESENTACION_JUAN AS PRESENTACION_JUAN;
END;

Espera sea útil ;)
